# Mock IOptionsMonitor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.2

How can I make an class instance manually of a class that requires an IOptionsMonitor in the constructor?

**My Class**

```
private readonly AuthenticationSettings _authenticationSettings;

public ActiveDirectoryLogic(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSettings> authenticationSettings)
{            
   _authenticationSettings = authenticationSettings.CurrentValue;
}
```

**My test**

```
AuthenticationSettings au = new AuthenticationSettings(){ ... };
var someOptions = Options.Create(new AuthenticationSettings());
var optionMan = new OptionsMonitor(someOptions);  // dont work.           
ActiveDirectoryLogic _SUT = new ActiveDirectoryLogic(au);
```

I tried to make an IOptionsMonitor object manually but can't figure out how.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsmonitor-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: In this case I would have just mocked the interface

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are calling the constructor of the [`OptionsMonitor<TOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsmonitor-1) class incorrectly.

In this case I would have just mocked the  `IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSettings>` interface

For example using Moq

```
AuthenticationSettings au = new AuthenticationSettings() { ... };
var monitor = Mock.Of<IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSettings>>(_ => _.CurrentValue == au);
ActiveDirectoryLogic _SUT = new ActiveDirectoryLogic(monitor);
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is another way to do it that doesn't involve trying to set the readonly CurrentValue field.

```
using Moq;

private IOptionsMonitor<AppConfig> GetOptionsMonitor(AppConfig appConfig)
{
  var optionsMonitorMock = new Mock<IOptionsMonitor<AppConfig>>();
  optionsMonitorMock.Setup(o => o.CurrentValue).Returns(appConfig);
  return optionsMonitorMock.Object;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Achieving the same in NSubstitute:

```
        var optionsMonitorMock = Substitute.For<IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSettings>>();
        optionsMonitorMock.CurrentValue.Returns(new AuthenticationSettings
        {
            // values go here
        });
```